# Relation between BGE framerate and Action framerate

Tags: python, scripting, animation, game-engine

By *BGE framerate* I mean the rate at which True pulse is fired (and thus attached Python controller script is executed) and by *Action framerate* I mean the rate at which the value returned by [`KX_GameObject.getActionFrame()`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.getActionFrame) is changing. (I've heard the term *Logic framerate* in the context of BGE, but I'm not sure if it is the same thing as *BGE framerate* I'm talking about :-/ Sorry!)

Here is a small snippet which I used for testing (which should clarify what I mean by *BGE frame* and *Action frame*):

```py
import bge

BGE_frame = 0

def main(cont):
    global BGE_frame

    arm = cont.owner
    if not arm.isPlayingAction():
        arm.playAction("run", 0, 45, play_mode=bge.logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_PLAY)

    print(BGE_frame)
    print(arm.getActionFrame())

    BGE_frame += 1
```

Using the above script for Python controller attached to an Always True sensor gives following result (the n-th *BGE frame* and corresponding *Action frame*):

http://pastebin.com/NK2RrVkR

As we can see, there is a significant difference in both frame-rates (e.g. the 11th *BGE frame* corresponds to the 4th *Action frame* and 16th *BGE frame* corresponds to the 6th *Action frame* -- so *roughly* 5 *BGE frames* corresponds to 2 *Action frames*).

Assuming that the action starts playing when BGE frame is 0, **in what way can we compute the *Action frame* from the *BGE frame* and vice-versa?** More precisely, I'm looking something like:

```py
import bge

BGE_frame = 0

def main(cont):
    global BGE_frame

    print(BGE_frame)
    print(BGE_frame_to_Animation_frame(BGE_frame)) # TODO: Outputs same result as above

    BGE_frame += 1
```

If it is needed here's the .blend file: http://wikisend.com/download/114182/framerate.blend

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved it as follows:

```
import bpy, bge

BGE_frame = 0

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
bpy_scene = bpy.data.scenes[scene.name]

BPY_FPS = bpy_scene.render.fps / bpy_scene.render.fps_base
BGE_FPS = bge.logic.getLogicTicRate()

BPY_BGE_RATIO = BPY_FPS / BGE_FPS

def BGE_frame_to_Animation_frame(BGE_frame):
    return BGE_frame * BPY_BGE_RATIO

def main(cont):
    global BGE_frame

    arm = cont.owner

    print(BGE_frame)
    print(arm.getActionFrame()) # Kept for comparison
    print(BGE_frame_to_Animation_frame(BGE_frame)) # Outputs approx. same result as above

    if not arm.isPlayingAction():
        arm.playAction("run", 0, 45, play_mode=bge.logic.KX_ACTION_MODE_PLAY)
        BGE_frame = 0
    else:
        BGE_frame += 1        

    print("\n")
```

I'm not sure of it is a good practice to access blender data from BGE, but it works :-) Comments/suggestions are welcome! Thanks.